# Tracking Facebook "Like" Referrals

Tags: facebook

This is not related to tracking Facebook "Likes" from an independent website.  I am specifically looking to find if the Facebook API supports tracking of referrals via Likes.  For example, I have an auto repair/maintenance client.  They want to add a promo to their Welcome landing page that allows users to refer their friends to "Like" the company page.  Once someone has referred 10+ "Like"'s, the company will then offer the referrer a free oil change or something.  Any thoughts or idea here?  I could not find a native App, but maybe I was not searching well enough.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but let me try:
You have a website `http://client.com/` which has a referral system, for example user **A** (which `id = 1234`) will have a referral URL:`http://client.com/landing_page.php?ref_id=1234`

And on this page, you have a Facebook like button. You need to "capture" if a certain likes to the Company page came from this URL?

Okay, Facebook provides an event to track when a user "likes" something. It's called [`edge.create`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) from there you can increment the user referrals.

For example on the page (`landing_page.php`) `http://client.com/landing_page.php?ref_id=1234` you'll have something like:

```js
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:'/referral_manager.php',
        data: {ref_id: <?php echo $ref_id_or_user_id; ?>}
    });
});
```

Where `$ref_id_or_user_id` can be taken from the URL when processing the page.

Now on the `referral_manager.php` you do your checking if a certain amount is reached to send a user a coupon (gift).

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**
One very important and crucial point here is to set the [Open Graph Meta Tags](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) to *the same* data in *all the pages*, not doing so...Facebook will treat these pages as different pages! For example **all** referral URLs (`http://client.com/landing_page.php?ref_id=xxxx` ...etc) should have:

```html
<meta property="og:title" content="Same Title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="company" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://client.com/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://client.com/img/logo_to_share.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Client Name" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="XXXXXXX" />
```

Comment: Wow, excellent answer!  Going to run this past a few people here and see if we can make headway on this.  Thanks so much for your insights.

Comment: here's a quick like to the fb javascript SDK page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/