# FB/Facebook current logged in user's pages list

Tags: facebook, list, fbml, fan-page

I will give a fan page link to any user in a facebook application, and tell that user to do like that page.

so how can I check that the specified user has clicked on like, I to check this by a script/FBML.

I want a script that returns true/false if I give a parameter of that page.

or I want to get pages list of that user so I can search that I want in that list.

How can I do this or is there any fbml which can extract pages list of current loggedin user.

Looking forward for your kind reply ans **sorry for my english.**

Thanks in advance...

Regards,

**Muhammad Hanif**

Answer (score 4):

Well I'm not sure what you are asking, but I'll try my best answering your "questions".

> I want a script that returns
>   true/false if I give a parameter of
>   that page.

So you already have the user id and the page id, you can check if the user is fan in two ways:
**pages.isFan:**

```
$isFan = $facebook->api(array(
    "method"    => "pages.isFan",
    "page_id"   => $page_id,
    "uid"       => $user_id
));
if($isFan === TRUE)
    echo "I'm a fan!";
```

**FQL:**

```
$result = $facebook->api(array(
    "method"    => "fql.query",
    "query"     => "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE uid=$user_id AND page_id=$page_id"
));
if(count($result))
    echo "$user_id is a fan!";
```

Source: [Facebook API: Check If A User Is Fan Of A Facebook Page](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/facebook-api-check-if-a-user-is-fan-of-a-facebook-page/20/).

You can also capture when the user "Like"s something, for this check [Tracking Facebook “Like” Referrals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220877/tracking-facebook-like-referrals/5221538#5221538).