# how receive an action of other page in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

here is the Plan:
there is a link in my web site , user click on it and a pop up open, in pop up window it show another web site that there is several links,the user should click on one link 
.
now , can I know which link did he clicked? and what was the respond ?
.
for example in some site for increasing instagram follower they say click on a link that refuse to some one page in instagram and if you follow him the pop up close and say you followed successfully but if you don't follow it understand. how does these web site works? also these website aren't third party app in instagram!

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: You use a javascript handler to react on the click event of the links. You prevent the default click action. Inside the handler you can do whatever you want with the information. For example you can send it to your server via an ajax request.

Comment: @arkascha can you show me by an example please?

Comment: Sorry, but there are millions of examples for attaching a javascript handler to a click event out there on the internet. I do not see any point in investing much time into the millions-and-first example. Just use google. Start by reading the documentation of jquerys function for that, I suggest: http://api.jquery.com/on/ There also is an introduction which should show you the options: https://learn.jquery.com/events/handling-events/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, I donnot think u can track the post click without adding some conversion tracking js to the targeted page (the website page in your pop up window.)

It may be possible if you are talking about webview where u can intercept all the requests.

regards
Hammer

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question, is it?

Comment: well, an answer can be "YES" or "NO". If u read through his question carefully, u will know your suggestion is invalid,

Comment: The OP asked _how_ that can be done, not _if_. So answering "no" does not make any sense at all. Especially since that is very well possible. Also it would be very interesting if you could share your statement instead of just dripping a nebulous hint.

Comment: Pls post ur code to let us know how to track the post click on another website where u donnot hv control without adding conversion tracking js.

Comment: No need to post code for this. That is standard client side logic. You register a handler to the click event. That allows you to do whatever you want with the information you have. What should be the issue here? Note that "a popup" is not "another website".

Comment: u barely understand his question. I hv no time for debate. A simple question. Post ur code of a page opening up www.google.com and track what user key in there from your page. If u can show any codes can do this, let us know.

Comment: I suggest you remove your "answer" here. It will get downvoted otherwise.

Comment: I suggest u stop giving invalid suggestions to him causes further efforts spent on sth not possible.

Comment: It is very well possible to interact with some page loaded into a window you control (opened).

Comment: @arkascha  i think you misunderstood , the pop up open an external website!

Comment: I can read, you know? That does not change anything.

Comment: @arkascha,  codes work better than talk. Post sample codes which u think can work, instead of "It is very well possible to interact with some page loaded into a window you control (opened)"

Comment: Let's just stop this. You clearly stated that you do not have any time for this anyway.

Comment: Yes, agree. @Ali, take whatever u think helpful for u, with a bit of google search urself.

Comment: @hammer actually it didn't help any way , could you please check this web site that is doing this plan http://addmefast.com

Comment: @Ali,  I see you have updated your question, which makes it a different case from what you raised previously. Pls read through https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.4  or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171270/does-facebook-like-button-return-any-value-php, you will hv a better idea of how to capture the return response for like or unlike. Hope it helps

Comment: @Hammer thank you so match, excellent

Comment: np. if it helps, pls mark it as an answer. Kindly raise your question more precisely next time. Too generic misleads sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.opener. I was unable to create a jsfiddle, but this should work. It will also not work locally.

main.html:

```
<script>
    function openPopup(){
        popup = window.open("child.html");
    }
</script>
<button onclick="openPopup()">open popup</button>
```

child.html

```
<script>
    function sendToParent(){
        window.opener.document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "clicked button";
    }
</script>
<button onclick="sendToParent()">send to parent</button>
```

Comment: I don't access to source of child !! it's on another site

Comment: Pls read his question carefully. He mentioned :"in pop up window it show another web site", which looks like the link in the pop-up comes from another site.

Comment: @Ali Then you can't access it.